# Ruby on rails: Need help formatting view from two different loops and two different partials into one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

Below are my two loops in two partial

**Loop 1 and partial 1**

```
<%@loop1.map do |p| %> 
<li>
    <%= image_tag p.product.image.url, :size=>"400x250"%>
    <br \>
    <p><%=p.product.text%></p>
    <div class="pull-right">From: <u><%=p.product.user%></u></div>
    <%end%>
</li>
<%end%>
```

**Loop 2 and partial 2**

```
<%@loop2.map do |p| %> 
<li>
    <%= image_tag p.product2.image.url, :size=>"400x250"%>
    <br \>
    <p><%=p.product2.text%></p>
    <div class="pull-right">From: <u><%=p.product2.user%></u></div>
    <%end%>
</li>
<%end%>
```

Now since I am using ajax on my index.html.erb file I i replace the below two divs with the data rendered above

```
<div class="loop1_results"></div>
<div class="loop2_results"></div>
```

So what happens now is `set of loop1 results` comes first and then comes `set of loop2 results`. What I want to do is alternate the order of the display. So it would show loop1 block and then loop2 block and so on.

How do i do it ?

Any suggestions or help is appreciated. If this can be done by into having all of it through one partial , how can i do it ?

**Update: Loop1 and loop2 are arrays and are of different sizes.**

Comment: Are `@loop1` and `@loop2` associated somehow?

Comment: nope. the data is being fetched from two different tables. Dont go by the naming, i am still testing and need to fix it.

Comment: Why use `map` if you're not using the return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Ajax, you probably have a .js.erb (or with Coffee); inside of the Javascript file you can chose where to load the data, for example, you may have:

```
$(".loop1_results").html("<%= render :partial => @partial1 %>");
$(".loop2_results").html("<%= render :partial => @partial2 %>");
```

And in the action you can choose with a "random" function which name save in `@partial1` and in `@partial2`

Also! I forgot you have different properties, you can pass additional variables to specify which variable do you need, or, you can create common methods between the collections to get the data

**UPDATE**

psharma you have the following code:

```
$("div. loop1_results").append("<%= escape_javascript (render :partial => 'loop1') %>");
$("div. loop1_results").append("<%= escape_javascript (render :partial => 'loop2') %>");
```

Now, instead or render 'loop1' and 'loop2' you are going to use the variables as I showed before, @partial1 and @partial2; this variables will contain 'loop1' and 'loop2', but the values that you save in those variables will be choosed by a "random" function, for example (this is a dummy example, please get this better hehe):

```
if (rand()*10).to_i%2 == 0
   @partial1 = 'loop1'
   @partial2 = 'loop2'
else
   @partial1 = 'loop2'
   @partial2 = 'loop1'
end
```

UPDATE #2

psharma I think I understand you, and I think the best way is to unify both collections into a single one, and to have only 1 partial. You said that both collections come from different tables (models), so what you can do in order to have only 1 partial is to create a method called `get_product` inside of the model of `p`, and here select if you get the `product1` or `product2`.

Now, you can unify both collections, but you can't simply do `@loop1 + @loop2`; what you can do is something like this (I haven't tested it, please also get this better hehe):

```
@data = []
total = @loop1.count + @loop2.count - 1
for i in 0..total
  if (i%2 == 0 || @loop2.empty?) && !@loop1.empty?
      @data << @loop1.pop
  elsif !@loop2.empty?
      @data << @loop2.pop 
  end
end
```

Comment: I am sorry but i didnt get what you saying. I already have these in my .js.erb file `$("div. loop1_results").append("<%= escape_javascript (render :partial => 'loop1') %>");
$("div. loop1_results").append("<%= escape_javascript (render :partial => 'loop2') %>");` I would appreciate if you could update the code in your solution. thanks

Comment: Okay i think this might work :p. Now where does if condition go. you said in the action. Do you mean in the controller? Can i have it inside my .js.erb file?

Comment: Put the condition in the action, you should always put the code in the controllers and in the views only the renders

Comment: ok gotcha. It sort of works now. You see if there are 10 products in loop1 and 15 in loop2 , either those 10 load first or the other 15 load first. but the set loads to gether. What I want to do is, one product from loop1, another product from loop2 and so on. am i making sense?:)

Comment: Ohhh I understand, the best way is to have only 1 partial... I will update the code

Comment: Last question: hmm, then i will just iterate over the data from @data right? Is it ok if i have this in the view or controller? Because i have a similar function in another app also and i plan on using the similar solution for that. But over there the loop is fetching data from two different apis/gems. any help? thanks

Comment: You can create a function, inside of the controller or ApplicationController if you are going to use it in other controller, and call to that function. You should always put the data management code in the controllers, and the business logic in the models... In the other case, there is no problem if you get the data from a different way, always that the data is stored in a collection

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `@loop1` and `@loop2` are the same size you can solve the given problem with the following code:

```
<% (0..@loop1.size - 1).each do |i| %>

<% p = @loop1[i] %>
<li>
    <%= image_tag p.product.image.url, :size=>"400x250"%>
    <br \>
    <p><%=p.product.text%></p>
    <div class="pull-right">From: <u><%=p.product.user%></u></div>
    <%end%>
</li>

<% p = @loop2[i] %>
<li>
    <%= image_tag p.product2.image.url, :size=>"400x250"%>
    <br \>
    <p><%=p.product2.text%></p>
    <div class="pull-right">From: <u><%=p.product2.user%></u></div>
    <%end%>
</li>

<%end%>
```

Without knowing more about your data structure I can't give you a cleaner solution.

Comment: both the loops derive data from two different tables. In future loop1 could fetch more data from the table and loop1 could fetch only 1 or two columns. So a more open solution is possible?

Comment: You need to add more information about your application and the models. Otherwise it is hard to give you the perfect answer. If loop1 and loop2 are not the same size you can check for the size and use the bigger one.

Comment: i got it. @pablo89 on the answer helped it. thanks for your time.